# How to paginate elements of an array after sorting on it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a controller method that sorts elements by a derived attribute.  I can print to the view as long as I don't attempt to paginate.  When I call `@foos = @foos.page params[:page]` I get the following error: `undefined method 'page' for #<Array:...>`

Can anyone provide some guidance here?  Thanks.

Here's the whole controller method:

```
def index_by_capacity
    if current_user.is_view_major?
      @foos = Foo.major_attr(:name)
    else
      @foos = Foo.order(:name)
    end


  @foos = @foos.sort_by! {|a| a.capacity_available.to_i }
  @total_foos = @foos.count

  @foos = @foos.page params[:page]

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @foos }
  end
end
```

Comment: Try `@foos.order(:capacity_available)` instead of `sort_by!` (the first will return an AR::Relation which can be paginated)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The `.sort_by!` method **returns an Array**, which has no method `page` (a ruby Array can't be paginated, you would have to implement it yourself or use an external lib).
- The **pagination works on ActiveRecord::Relation objects**, returned by queries like `.where` or `.order`
- **In you case**, you should do an order at the DB-level (faster than doing a sort via Ruby):

  ```
  @foos.order(:capacity_available)
  ```
- If the `capacity_available` attribute is a String (not an Integer), you can **CAST it as an INT**:

  ```
  @foos.order('CAST(capacity_available AS INT) ASC')
  ```

(You may need to edit the `CAST()` function, it should work on PostGreSQL, not sure about MySQL)

Comment: capacity_available was a derived attribute but I was able to find a creative solution by ordering by a db element.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to continue using an array instead of an active record relation object, you can simply include `WillPaginate::Collection`.

**From WillPaginate Documentation**

Previously, all objects returned from paginate methods were of WillPaginate::Collection type. This is no longer true; in Active Record 3, the paginate and page methods return a Relation that is extended to look like a WillPaginate::Collection. Similarly, DataMapper returns a regular DataMapper::Collection that is also extended.

Both ActiveRecord::Relation and DataMapper::Collection are lazy arrays in the way that they don't execute any SQL queries until the point when data is needed. This makes them better than ordinary arrays.

The WillPaginate::Collection class is still available, however, and mostly unchanged.

The Array#paginate method still exists, too, but is not loaded by default. If you need to paginate static arrays, first require it in your code:

require 'will_paginate/array'